# Is it best practice to have an empty parent project in Maven?

Tags: maven, pom.xml, parent-pom

I'm quite new with multi module projects in Maven, I just learned that in creating a parent project, you basically just need to change the packaging to 'pom' -> `<packaging>pom</packaging>`. Given this if you run `mvn package` on your parent project, it will not generate a jar file if you have source code in it.
I found a way though by using plugins, you can generate a jar file even when you are executing the parent pom:

```
... 
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
<build>
<plugins>
 <plugin>
     <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
     <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
     <version>2.2</version>
     <executions>
         <execution>
             <id>my-execution-id</id>
             <phase>package</phase>
             <goals>
                 <goal>jar</goal>
             </goals>
         </execution>
     </executions>
 </plugin>
</plugins>          
</build>
...
```

My question now is, is it best practice having source code within your parent project? Or is it better to keep it empty and just have it for plugin/dependency management etc?

Comment: In that case, I would rather check the popular java repository on github to check how they are doing. For eg,. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot

Comment: First if your packaging is pom don't try to get code in that project cause it's intended not to have code..that violates the idea of convention over configuration..If you have code to compile/tests/package that a multi module project has a child which has packaging `jar` and that contains the code and has the parent as defined earlier...

Answer (score 1):

Don't put source code into your parent POM project. It violates expectations and there is not real advantage. Put the code into the modules. Follow @khmarbaise's comment.

Answer (score -1):

If you need a template for a whole company or something like that, then just create a parent pom is fine (you just need a pom file, don't need to create an empty project). In there, you can configure something like repositories, plugins that you want, etc.

It can be something like this

```
parent-pom.xml (for the whole company, where you configure common stuff, don't put code here)
|_ projectA-parent-pom.xml (team A, doing project A)
|    |_ projectA-child-pom-1.xml
|    |_ projectA-child-pom-2.xml
|_ projectB-parent-pom.xml (team B, doing project B)
     |_ projectB-child-pom-1.xml
     |_ projectB-child-pom-2.xml
     |_ projectB-child-pom-3.xml
```

Edit: My answer is not good. So I updated it.